# Sobre SSL's CxB

Tags: ssl, dns, wildcard

recentemente comecei a me interessar muito sobre programação web. Apartir de inumeros tutoriais assistidos em diversas plataformas, tais como youtube, vimeo, blogs e forums, a fim de por em pratica os conhecimentos que adquiri, instalei em minha VPS o Apache e comprei um dominio na Hostinger, só pra dar uma aparencia mais "profissional" e dedicada. Confesso que a intenção final disto é criar um site com uma area de 'Account & Login' e também criar uma Interface Web para um script do qual desenvolvi para 'Idlear Jogos na Steam'.

a pouco mais de 1 mês eu não sabia nem oque era um Node.js e hoje, graças aos tutoriais e este fórum, aprendi muita coisa e pretendo continuar aprendendo cada vez mais.

Me considero uma pessoa que "aprende rápido e fácil" e graças a essa """habilidade""" consigo me virar 'sozinho'.

Uma duvida que não me ficou clara foi sobre o SSL da CloudFlare e gostaria da indicação de vocês. Atualmente estou usando o DNS deles, pois, não achei nenhum tutorial bom para o BIND9.

Tenho o dominio "www.officialyume.xyz" e criei dentro da .conf do apache um subdominio "store.officialyume.xyz". Ambos os arquivos ficam em pastas diferentes da minha VPS. Portanto tive muita dificuldade em instalar os certificados SSL's Gratuitos/Trial existentes. Em contra-partida me surgiu uma opção viável dentro do proprio CloudFlare.

[image: Preço CloudFlare]

A duvida é: Quais destes planos irão cobrir o meu dominio e subdominio?
Me resta outra alternativa além de pagar 80 Dolares num SSL WildCard?

Minha config DNS atual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou aberto a todas e possiveis criticas, opinioes e sugestoes. Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Através deste painel você consegue inserir outros tipos de certificados ou somente os oferecidos pelo plano? Se sim, o "Let's Encrypt" poderia resolver seu problema, além de gratuito. Eu o utilizo nos meus domínios e nunca tive problemas.

Comment: Não, não é possivel. Tentei fazer diretamente pelo Apache, colocando os certificados na VPS e declarando-os na .conf do Apache, mas o CloudFlare bloqueava o acesso HTTPS alegando que os Certificados eram invalidos.

Comment: Muito estranho, por se tratar de VPS que é gerenciável por você mesmo, o CloudFlare bloquear o acesso HTTPS. Após informar os certificados e reiniciar o serviço do Apache é gerado algum tipo de erro?

Comment: Não nenhum erro é apresentado pelo Apache. O CloudFlare informa o erro 526 identico a este `https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/200249454/httpbin.canhazip.com___526__Invalid_SSL_certificate.png` porem a conexão via http funciona corretamente

Comment: Você já verificou se a porta 443 está liberada no Firewall?

Comment: Sim, inclusive a OVH informa que o serviço está operante, vide: https://i.imgur.com/XEhsJbV.png .